# Картинки из БД не выводятся на сайт

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

В БД для каждого товара хранится путь к его фотографии

На странице пытаюсь вывести картинки, название и ценник. Все кроме картинок выводится

```
@model IEnumerable<Davai.Models.ItemList>
@{
    Layout = "/Views/MasterView.cshtml";
}


<main class="main__container">
    <div class="shop__container">
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <div class="item__icon">
                <img src="@item.Image" alt="no photo" width="260" height="419" />
                <h1>@item.Name</h1>
                <h2>@item.Price</h2>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Этот путь правильный? Ведёт в Web root?

Comment: Получилось исправить удалив base href в body, там была бурда написана ))